# Rendering an email preview in Vue

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating an internal messaging app in Vue and would like to expose a limited number of predefined variables for a user to choose from when sending a templated message (name, department, etc.).

I'm planning on displaying the rendered variables in a "preview" component which ideally would take the raw html, complete with {{variables}}, fetch the values for the variables and render the preview.

Judging from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components there are a number of options that would seem to work, is there an objectively better/worse solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue while creating a chart editor.

Instead of sending HTML to the component, you can send a object which consists of your variables as a prop to the component and then render the HTML inside preview components.That will provide live preview feature to the user.

Comment: I would still need to get the HTML over to the component though right?  How would you suggest I handle that?

Comment: As you have mentioned that email body is templated so the HTML content should go inside component's templated section.Component's HTML content contains your templated message and some data variables (which will be replaced by component's props).

Comment: If you could provide a jsfiddle.I would be happy to help.